# RxJS keep order after partition

Tags: rxjs

I have an `Observable` which emits keys. Some of values for the keys are available locally and some need to be retrieved from the backend. I split the observable with:

```
const [keysLocal, keysServer] 
         = keysObservable.pipe(partition(key => valueMap.has(key)));
```

I then retrieve both values and output them to the same `Subject`:

```
keysLocal.pipe(map(key => valueMap.get(key)))
         .subscribe(value => valuesSubject.next(value));

keysServer.pipe(switchMap(key => server.slowRequest(key)))
         .subscribe(value => valuesSubject.next(value));
```

This works fine for most cases. However, when `keysObservable` emits `keyServer_524` and `keyLocal_314` in quick succession then `valueLocal_314` is retrieved and output before `valueServer_524`. This leads to values output from `valuesSubject` to not be in the same order as the keys output from `keysObservable`.

What is the most idiomatic way to make sure that values are not emitted out-of-order? Since for my use-case I only care about the latest value it is okay to drop previous requests (`valueServer_524` in the example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that after `partition` the order of keys is lost. There is no way to reconstruct the order of the source observable. As a result I settled for a solution in which I use `switchMap` to get the latest value without partitioning the observable.

```
getValueObservable(key) {
  if (valueMap.has(key)) {
     return of(valueMap.get(key));
  } else {
     return server.slowRequest(key);
  }
}

keysObservable.pipe(switchMap(getValueObservable))
              .subscribe(value => valuesSubject.next(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the order in which subscriptions are created.

I'd say a quick way to fix this is to use the `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` operator on `keysLocal` so that it will output after `keysServer`:

```js
keysLocal.pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler), map(key => valueMap.get(key)))
         .subscribe(value => valuesSubject.next(value));

keysServer.pipe(switchMap(key => server.slowRequest(key)))
         .subscribe(value => valuesSubject.next(value));
```